# MFMessageComposeViewController inserts a new line at the end

Tags: ios, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller, imessage

I've made a little app for iOS where I use Apple's `MFMessageComposeViewController` to send a SMS/iMessage. Very soon I saw that it always inserts a new line (`\n`) at the end of the text to be sent.
I checked how it does in other apps which are using this `MFMessageComposeViewController` and it turned out that the new line appears there too, so it should not be my fault.

Is there a way to tell `MFMessageComposeViewController` not to insert this annoying line, or maybe a possibility to delete it by myself after displaying the View Controller?

Comment: Being able to directly change the text would be a security problem. Raise a bug with Apple.